# Laravel wherenotexists returning null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following piece of code

```
 $not_paid = Tenant::where('property_id', $property_id)
            ->whereNotExists(function ($query) use ($property_id) {
                $query->select('user_id')
                ->from('rent_paids'); 
            })
            ->get();
```

which is supposed to get all the tenants in a certain property, look them up in the `rent_paids` table and return the users who are not in the `rent_paids` table, as follows:

tenants table

| Id | user_id | property_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |

rent_paids

| Id | user_id | property_id | amount_paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3000 |

I want to be able to return the users in the tenants table and not in the rent_paids table. In this case, users `2 and 3`. But the above code returns an empty array.

Comment: Doesn't `->whereNotExists()` takes 2 values/arguments? Where not exist in what?

Comment: @DimitriMostrey No, a [closure is correct](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-exists-clauses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the where clause to tie it back to the original table.

```
$not_paid = Tenant::where('property_id', $property_id)
        ->whereNotExists(function ($query) use ($property_id) {
            $query->select('user_id')
            ->from('rent_paids')
            ->whereColumn('tenants.user_id', '=', 'rent_paids.user_id'); 
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: I think this needs `whereColumn` though it looks like a `join` might be more appropriate than a `whereNotExists`. Also it might need a tie in with `$property_id` but from the question it is very unclear how that ties in.

Comment: You're right, it does need to be whereColumn. I was following the example on https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-exists-clauses